# Can I change a ButtonToggleStyle deselected background color in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

Toggles in SwiftUI have a `.tint` modifier to set their color when toggled on but I'd like to set a toggle's background color when off, specifically when using `.toggleStyle(.button)`. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Do it in the same way

```
    Toggle("Test", isOn: $isOn)
        .toggleStyle(.button)
        .tint(.red)
```

[image: demo]

Off state is as expected:

[image: demo2]

Comment: Thanks, but this only works when the button toggle is on. I'd like to know how to do this when the toggle is off. I had my title correct before but my question body was unclear. I've updated it to fix this.

Comment: It works fine and correct for OFF as well, ie. inverses colors.

Comment: Thank you, but this still doesn't address my specific need/original question. You're correct in that it inverts the color for deselection but imagine a scenario where this button is against a white background. Now you have red text in white button in a white background. The button boundary isn't immediately apparent to the user. I want the deselected button to have some other color to visually separate it from the background.

Comment: You can just extend with custom style that, say, apply additional border or something. This is default behavior, but we can customise it as we need.

Comment: Right, so I guess my original real question would be how to extend ButtonToggleStyle to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm clearly late to the party on this one, but I was just playing around with the topic and figured I'd share the code below. I'm just substituting the background with a clipShape. I doubt it's the most efficient way, but I think it addresses your question.

[image: Here's the result]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isOn = true
    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: $isOn, label: {
            if isOn {
                Label("Test ", systemImage: "checkmark.circle.fill")
                    .tint(Color.black)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5.0, style: .continuous))
                
            } else {
                Label("Test ", systemImage: "checkmark.circle")
                    .tint(Color.black)
                    .background(Color.green)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5.0, style: .continuous))
            }
        })
        .tint(Color.clear)
        .toggleStyle(.button)
    }
}
```

- XCode 14.3.1
- Swift 5